# How to Implement Google Maps Api without credit card?

Tags: android, maps, in-app-billing, billing

Can anybody please tell me the process for implementing Google Maps api in android project.I have tried but it needs google billing account enabled and it requires credit card details. Does anyone know how to implement this functionality without a credit card?

Comment: You can't do it now

Comment: google won't let you pass without credit card